# mysql workbench load data local infile cannot find file or directory

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Anyone else having problem using:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:/PRODUCT_GROUP_UPLOAD.CSV' into TABLE ats_store.product_group
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' 
ESCAPED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
(product_group_id,name,price,description,image,start_time,end_time,start_date,end_date,product_code,delivery_format);
```

Mysql Workbench has been buggy for a few weeks now, but I can't even find the file. Also, I updated today!

I get:

```
Error Code: 2. File 'c:\PRODUCT_GROUP_UPLOAD.CSV' not found (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)
```

I have loaded other files, but can't seem to get this one loaded? It's def in the folder I specify!

Keep in mind that i already played with the slashes, forward, backward, double forward, double backward, etc...

Answer (score 8):

> Windows path names are specified using forward slashes rather than
>   backslashes. If you do use backslashes, you must double them.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Comment: Couldn't get around the problem. I am now using mysql workbench and Toad MYSQL. The import in Toad is pesky, but it works.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem your path should be using ""

```
"C:\\PRODUCT_GROUP_UPLOAD.CSV" if running from workbench
```

Comment: Had to come back here to remember how it was. You must also have write permission in the destination folder.

Comment: Thank you that solved my problem here too. So on Windows, I have verified that 2 things are important: 1) LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 2) using '\\' for directories.

Comment: @Zek101 can you elaborate the solution, because yet I'm facing the same issues.

Comment: @mevada.yogesh : this is quite an old issue I had, and I don't have any trace left but if I remember well:

Comment: if you are on Windows, you should : 1) type "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:\\PRODUCT_GROUP_UPLOAD.CSV' into TABLE ats_store.product_group" instead of "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:/PRODUCT_GROUP_UPLOAD.CSV' into TABLE ats_store.product_group",  and 2) you must also include "LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' somewhere after it", after having specified the fields and lines separators

Answer (score 1):

LOAD DATA LOCAL requires the file to be on the client machine. Is this the case for you?

Since you wrote you have already loaded other files I assume your server and client have been the same for all attempts and only this single file fails to load. I write this because LOCAL support can be switched off (see also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data-local.html).

Mike

Comment: yes, same machine. it's like the command just stopped working. Workbench has been acting strange, crashing, not opening, not connecting.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the data file to a test directory not under "documents and settings" or its children. Windows may be restricting access to that area. Then test your LOAD INFILE statement again.

Comment: The path in the question is `c:\PRODUCT_GROUP_UPLOAD.CSV`. That's not under `Documents and Settings`.